# Where should I give feedback about the new Blender 2.80?

Tags: versions

Where can I give feedback about the Blender 2.80 beta? Right now I am testing it and I would like to give my feedback, because it is suggested I should do so on blender.org website.

Comment: did you try here https://devtalk.blender.org/c/user-feedback ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender

Comment: I think this is relevant. Giving feedback is important. Of course this is not a high quality question, no research effort whatsoever is shown as the information is clearly given at the same place where users are encouraged to give feedback, but I think it could be considered not to be off topic as well. Giving feedback and being part of the open source community could be part of using Blender. There is of course the question if one should be giving feedback if they are not even able to find a clear link to the place to do so... Might not be the good quality feedback they are looking for...

Answer (score 2):

You should look for that information on the same website - blender.org. There are links to developer forums on the download page at the bottom including this one: https://devtalk.blender.org/ There is a section called User Feedback in it:

[image]